# How can i add a next and previous button at the segmented Controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar, uisegmentedcontrol

In my application I have a segmented controller at navigation bar and until now I have 6 buttons there.

But now I want to add more 5 buttons with these 6 buttons at segmented controller but problem is I want to add an previous and next button at segmented controller to see previous buttons and next buttons of the segmented controller.

NOTE THAT: I know how can set an segmented controller at navigation bar.  Until now, I have become able to set segmented controller at navigation bar.

If I explain again then it should be look like this:

`< Previous | A | B | C | D | E | next >`
when I will press `next` then it will show like this:
`< previous | B | C | D | E | F | next >`
like this for previous button.

Anybody help me. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of user experience, segmented controls are not designed to be used this way.

You could force it if you really wanted to, by modifying the text on the appropriate segments when either the first or last segment was selected and then clearing the selection, but users are accustomed to how segmented controls are supposed to work, and this could be confusing (not to mention it may fail Apple's review process).

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SegmentedControl/Articles/SegmentedControlCode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002250-129646[link] ....can i do this using this link example???...

Comment: can i do this using uitoolbar??...if it is possible then can u give me an example or source code please...