# How can i add a next and previous button at the segmented Controller on a navigation bar in iphone application development?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I am in great trouble....How can i set next and previous button/arrow at my segmented bar...if anyone need brief about my problem then please see this link...[How can i add a next and previous button at the segmented Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222018/how-can-i-add-a-next-and-previous-button-at-the-segmented-controller)

i have attached an image to understand the problem...so anybody help me please....
[image]

NOTE THAT: In my current project it has more than 5 buttons to add at the segmented bar so when i will press next/previous arrow then segmented bar should be move from his place.If my question is not clear to you then please see my another link....

Thanks in Advance

EDIT:

```
UIBarButtonItem *previousBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] //init];
                                      initWithTitle:@"<"
                                      style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                      target:self 
                                      action:@selector(previousBarButtonAction:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = previousBarButtonItem;

[previousBarButtonItem release];

UIBarButtonItem *nextBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] //init];
                                      initWithTitle:@">"
                                      style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                      target:self 
                                      action:@selector(nextBarButtonAction:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nextBarButtonItem;

[nextBarButtonItem release];

//This Portion For UIToolbar

topToolBar = [UIToolbar new];
topToolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
[topToolBar sizeToFit];
topToolBar.frame = CGRectMake(50, 410, 280, 50);

//Add buttons
UIBarButtonItem *systemItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                                                             target:self
                                                                             action:@selector(pressButton1:)];

UIBarButtonItem *systemItem2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction
                                                                             target:self
                                                                             action:@selector(pressButton2:)];

UIBarButtonItem *systemItem3 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera
                                target:self action:@selector(pressButton3:)];

//Use this to put space in between your toolbox buttons
UIBarButtonItem *flexItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                          target:nil
                                                                          action:nil];

//Add buttons to the array
NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: systemItem1, flexItem, systemItem2, flexItem, systemItem3, nil];

//release buttons
[systemItem1 release];
[systemItem2 release];
[systemItem3 release];
[flexItem release];

//add array of buttons to toolbar
[topToolBar setItems:items animated:NO];

self.navigationItem.titleView = topToolBar;
```

this is my current coding position now i have 4 buttons in the uitoolbar but only 3 button can see so i want to move this toolbar when i will press next or previous button to see the others button whose are out of frame of uitoolbar??

EDIT:

I able to scroll the navigation bar item using uiview animation but now my problem is when i press the next/prev button then it is moving from the current place according to the changing of the coordinate of the uitoolbar and moving over the pre/next baritem frame whose are not in the uitoolbar items. but it should be wothin a uiview and should change the coordinate within the uiview not out of the view...now tell me what can i do for this problem.

Comment: Have you already created the UINavigationController?

Comment: This is a dupe of your other question. If you are trying to clarify the question, you should do it in the original,not create a duplicate.

Comment: @Rickay yes i have already created my navigationController.

Comment: @XJones: ok thanx for your advice...i will follow this next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly in figure the NavigationBar you are seeing is actually `UIToolBar`. Unfortunately it is not possible to add anymore controls on the `UINavigationBar`. But you can achieve exactly same UI with `UIToolBar` where you can add any controls.

So to achieve this use `UIToolBar` and not `UINavigationBar`. Also use `UIBarButtonItem` with custom title to achieve *Next* and *Previous* functionality.

**EDIT**

Here are few links for example of `UIToolBar`

1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43658/How-to-Make-a-Toolbar-with-UIToolbar
2. http://osmorphis.blogspot.com/2009/05/multiple-buttons-on-navigation-bar.html
3. http://atastypixel.com/blog/making-uitoolbar-and-uinavigationbars-background-totally-transparent/

But this all explains using codes. Instead using **Interface Builder**, it becomes too easy to use `UIToolBar` (if coding is not so important).

Comment: This is incorrect. You can create his picture with a `UINavigationBar`.

Comment: Can you explain why it is not possible with UINavigationBar.

Comment: Can you send me some example or source code???Because i did not work on this before.

Comment: Actually i need duplicate interface for my application so please give me an example because i did not work on UIToolBar before....

Comment: please see my edited answer for using UIToolBar. But if you are using Interface Builter to build UI, then I recommend you not to go into either of links if you are familiar of how to achieve IBOutlets and give IBActions to controls. Using UIToolBar is as easy as using UIButton.

Comment: @Anand: Please go through link http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html  Here in **Navigation Bar** Guidelines it is explained. **Use a toolbar instead of a navigation bar**

Comment: At first thanks for your reply.Now i have another problem.I have edited my question now please tell me what can i do????

Comment: Do you mean that you want to scroll the NavigationBar items?? If so then you need to add UIScrollView with horizontal scrolling. I havn't face with horizontal scrolling in navigation. But I recommend you to find other way out..

Answer (score 0):

I think this is being slightly overcomplicated- can you not just set the text of the two UIBarButtonItems to "<" and ">"?

Comment: Actually it is becoming too much complicated to me....i just need to make this UI...i don't know how?? If i need to use navigationbar then i will do..if i need to use uitoolbar then also i have to do...but i have to do...if you can then help me how can i do this??? If you can then send an example or source code...

Comment: If you already have a UINavigationBar, then just add bar buttons to it in Interface Builder and set the text to "<" or ">"

Comment: but i want to add more uibaritem and when i will press next/prev button then uitoolbar will move and will display the other buttons whose are out of toolbar frame.Thats mean next and prev button will take same place when i will press next button then toolbar will move to the right and it will see the buttons whose were out of the toolbar frame.same as for previous button...